# How to test mathematically if a number contains the highest digit of its radix?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Is there a way to test mathematically if a number contains the highest digit of its radix, and if so how?

For example, 101 in base 2 contains the digit 1, highest in base 2; but 101 in base 3 does not contain 2, the highest digit in base 3.

Additionally - perhaps ideally for my purpose  - given a number in base 10, is there a way to test mathematically if it would contain the highest digit of its radix if expressed in another base -- for example, 5 (base 10) would contain the highest digit in base 2 (101) as well as in base 3 (12).

Answer (score 1):

Not easily.  Can you tell easily that $34123894712470343581343468134781378$ has a $9$ in it, while $134554345636636546576678450605606460$ does not?  There are operations to find if there is a $9$ at the front or the back-modulo for the back and limits on the logarithm for the front.  If you have lots of digits, it is almost certain that there is a $9$ in there somewhere, but it is hard to be sure.

In base $2$ it is easy.  Check if the number is not equal to $0$.  In other bases it is just like base $10$